# Manage touch events to draw lines in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I am coding a game with cocos2d-x in c++.

In my game scene i will place some instances of my class CircleSprite (Which is an extension of Layer where i create multiple items and set them like child of CircleSprite.

In my scene the user should touch one circle and connect it to another one by moving the finger until another circle is reached. While doing this a line (sprite or draw it dosen't matter) should appear and follow the finger until reach the choosen circle.
I'm new with cocos2d programming and i'm not a c++ expert...i don't know how to manage the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this official tutorial 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/User_Tutorials-Dragging_a_Sprite_Around_the_Screen

Also check the version of cocos2dx for which this tutorial was written. If yours is a lower version then v2.3, then you just need to override `onTouchesBegin and onTouchesEnded onTouchesMoved` functions of the layer, the are already registered with the touch events.